# Calculate $E[X^2-2|X|]$ and $E[X^2] $,$E[X|X|]$

Tags: probability

Calculate $E[X^2-2|X|]$ and E[X|X|]if we have a probability function $p$ such that

$P(X=-3=\frac{3}{8})$
$P(X=0=\frac{1}{8})$
$P(X=3=\frac{1}{4})$
$P(X=4=\frac{1}{4})$

**My work**

We know $E[X^2]=9(\frac{3}{8})+0(\frac{1}{8})+9(\frac{1}{4})+16(\frac{1}{4})=\frac{77}{8}$

Now, i need calculate $E[X^2-2|X|]$

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)=X^2-2|X|$

Then by a result we know $E[X^2-2|X|]=E[X^2]-2E[|X|]=\frac{77}{8}-2\frac{23}{8}=\frac{31}{8}$

I don't know how calculate $E[X|X|]$
But here i'm a little stuck. Can someone help me?

**Note:** $E[X]$ is the expected value of $X$

Comment: Expectations is linear so $E(X^2-2|X|)=E(X^2)-2E(|X|)$.

Comment: and $E[|X|]$ can be calculated using a function $g$? @AnyAD

Comment: And you have $E(X^2)$. Just find $E(|X|)$ like you had before... $E(|X|)=\sum_x |X|*P(X)$

Comment: @TonyHellmuth a question, $E(|X|)= |x_1|p(x_1)+|x_2|p(x_2)+....$ ?

Comment: Yes :) Of course x only takes -3,0,3 and 4. I think you a confused on the expression of an expectation.

Comment: Thanks for all! @TonyHellmuth

Comment: @TonyHellmuth i got a problem calculating $E[X|X|]$ Can you help me with that?

Comment: Ah I thought you might ask that :P Think of the definition of $|X|$. What happens when X is positive and negative?

Comment: i get $E[X^2]$ and if X is negative then i get $E[-X^2]=-E[X^2]$ no? @TonyHellmuth

Comment: Well would $E[X|X|]=\sum_x X|X|*P(X)$?

Comment: @TonyHellmuth Your splitting is basically right. For $X<0$, We have $-x^2\cdot f_X(x)$ and for $X\geq 0$ we have $x^2\cdot f_X(x)$

Comment: @callculus yay! Thanks for the clarification! :)